# How to trace who sent mail with attachment

Tags: email, information-gathering

Yesterday someone emailed me a malicious .bat script.

I have his email (he used Gmail) and of course I can't track him using mail header. So I checked the .bat file details but I only see my computer name.

So how can I track him down using the file's information? Is there anyway else?

Answer (score 1):

You should contact [Gmail abuse](https://support.google.com/mail/contact/abuse), if the headers clearly show the message is actually from Gmail and the message is against their policies or terms of use. If the `From:` address is spoofed, you can use mail headers to track the actual originating server, but it's likely a hijacked server without any actual connection to the offender. It's still worth to contact them, just to give them an advice to check their systems and remove possible malware.

The file may or may not contain some clues, but if it only causes harm without any benefit to the attacker, there's probably nothing. However, most malware try to benefit somehow, for example sending your confidential information somewhere, and following that information might get you somewhere. On frauds involving money the money is usually easier to track, but that would be job for the police. Frankly, that's when the damage has already occurred, and we try to prevent it.

Best way to handle this would still be to **remove the message and move on**. Spammers have been among us [for decades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_email_spam) and they aren't going anywhere. Sometimes they even come up  with something new, like the ["self-abusing" blackmail scam](http://www.thatsnonsense.com/extortion-email-scam-claims-video-email-recipient-self-abusing/); with Bitcoin involved it's impossible to track the money, and the perpetrator doesn't need access to the mailbox for the originating address.